# Codewarrior 10.5 broken links from problems window to errors in code

Tags: codewarrior, nxp-microcontroller

Typically when I compile a project I am working on in Codewarrior, the Problems window displays the errors and warnings it finds. From there, I am able to click on the errors and I will be linked to the location of the error in the code. In the current project I am working on, the errors are displayed in the problems window, but they do not link to the error. It shows the correct file and path, but the hyperlink to the location in the code is broken. In the console window, I can use the Next/Previous error buttons to navigate to error, but I can't do this from the Problems window - which I find easier to read. I know that this error is limited to this project, because I have opened other projects since this started happening and do not experience this problem in those projects. When I started this project, I copied an existing Codewarrior 10.5 project that does not have this issue and began changing names and editing. I have a suspicion that I might have missed something during this conversion process, but I am running out of places to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the exact reason for this error, but I did correct it by deleting the folders in the workspace folder and re-importing the project.